# Restrictions of unboxed types

Tags: haskell, type-families, newtype

I wonder why unboxed types in Haskell have these restrictions:

1. You cannot define a newtype for unboxed type:

   ```
   newtype Vec = Vec (# Float#, Float# #)
   ```

   but you can define type synonim:

   ```
   type Vec = (# Float#, Float# #)
   ```
2. Type families can't return unboxed type:

   ```
   type family Unbox (a :: *) :: # where
       Unbox Int    = Int#
       Unbox Word   = Word#
       Unbox Float  = Float#
       Unbox Double = Double#
       Unbox Char   = Char#
   ```

Are there some fundamental reasons behind this, or it's just because no one asked for this features?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Parametric polymorphism in Haskell relies on the fact that all values of `t :: *` types are uniformly represented as a pointer to a runtime object. Thus, the same machine code works for all instantiations of polymorphic values.

Contrast polymorphic functions in Rust or C++. For example, the identity function there still has type analoguous to `forall a. a -> a`, but since values of different `a` types may have different sizes, the compilers have to generate different code for each instatiation. This also means that we can't pass polymorphic functions around in runtime boxes:

```
data Id = Id (forall a. a -> a)
```

since such a function would have to work correctly for arbitrary-sized objects. It requires some additional infrastructure to allow this feature, for example we could require that a runtime `forall a. a -> a` function takes extra implicit arguments that carry information about the size and constructors/destructors of `a` values.

Now, the problem with `newtype Vec = Vec (# Float#, Float# #)` is that even though `Vec` has kind `*`, runtime code that expects values of some `t :: *` can't handle it. It's a stack-allocated pair of floats, not a pointer to a Haskell object, and passing it to code expecting Haskell objects would result in segfaults or errors.

In general `(# a, b #)` isn't necessarily pointer-sized, so we can't copy it into pointer-sized data fields.

Type families returning `#` types are disallowed for related reasons. Consider the following:

```
type family Foo (a :: *) :: # where
  Foo Int = Int#
  Foo a   = (# Int#, Int# #)

data Box = forall (a :: *). Box (Foo a)
```

Our `Box` is not representable runtime, since `Foo a` has different sizes for different `a`-s. Generally, polymorphism over `#` would require generating different code for different instantiations, like in Rust, but this interacts badly with regular parametric polymorphism and makes runtime representation of polymorphic values difficult, so GHC doesn't bother with any of this.

(Not saying though that a usable implementation couldn't possibly be devised)

Comment: "problem with `newtype Vec = Vec (# Float#, Float# #)` is that even though `Vec` has kind `*`" But why? Why it has to have kind `*` ? When i write `type Vec = (# Float#, Float# #)` Vec has kind `#`, so I expect newtype to have kind `#` too.

Comment: `type Vec = ...` is just a synonym. `newtype` defines, well, a new type that's different from the type of the wrapped value. It happens so that all Haskell constructs for defining new types return in kind `*`. `newtype`-s for unboxed types would require a large chunk of the infrastructure I mentioned above for enabling polymorphism over differently sized objects, or else it would be only usable monomorphically, which would render them not particularly better compared to just using the wrapped type.

Comment: @AndrásKovács It could be made of kind `#`, but then e.g. `id :: a -> a` can't be specialized for `a ~ Vec` since `a::*`.  This limitation is related to the fact that the runtime handles boxed data uniformly (with pointers) when you want to pass raw unboxed data around, so you need a custom `id` for each unboxed type. Not too different to Java's inability to have generics such as `T<int>` since `int` is not a reference type.

Comment: There are in fact [plans](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/UnliftedDataTypes) to split up `#` to separate out the *boxed* unlifted types (like `Array#`) from it. Those *do* have uniform representations and could allow parametric polymorphism, and one of the proposals is to allow `newtype` for them.

Answer (score 4):

A `newtype` would allow one to define class instances

```
instance C Vec where ...
```

which can not be defined for unboxed tuples. Type synonyms instead do not offer such functionality.

Also, `Vec` would not be a boxed type. This means that you can no longer instantiate type variables with `Vec` in general, unless their kind allows it. For instance `[Vec]` should be disallowed. The compiler should keep track of "regular" newtypes and "unboxed" newtypes in some way. This will have, I think, the only benefit of allowing the data constructor `Vec` to wrap unboxed values at compile time (since it is removed at runtime). This would probably be not enough useful to justify making the necessary changes to the type inference engine, I guess.

Comment: Oh, it should've been my 3rd question: why can't you define class over  unboxed types like this: `class C (u :: # ) where ...` ?

Comment: "Vec would not be a boxed type" Why it has to be that way? Type synonim   `type Vec = (# Float#, Float# #)` has kind `#` why `newtype` hasn't?

Comment: "The compiler should keep track of "regular" newtypes and "unboxed" newtypes in some way." Is regular kind-checking not enough?

Comment: @AlexeyVagarenko I guess this strongly depends on the Haskell runtime. András below describes it better than I can.